# couponic on cPanel error: Declaration of UWorkletAccessRule::isUserAllowed()

Tags: php, yii, cpanel

I'm trying to host couponic on cPanel, but I'm getting this error message:

**Declaration of UWorkletAccessRule::isUserAllowed() should be compatible with CAccessRule::isUserAllowed($user, $controller, $action, $ip, $verb)**

[image]

Comment: at what point does the error happen? Can't even tell if this is code related, or cpanel configuration related.

Comment: Trying to intsall @Andrew 'yourdomain.com/install'